# How to make a collapsible data-role="list-divider"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to create a jQuery mobile formatted content listview like [the demo on the jQuery Mobile site](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/listview/).

What I'd like to have is the `data-role="list-divider"` be collapsible. I've tried to have the `<li>` have both `data-role="list-divider"` and `data-role="collapsible"` (as well as `data-role="list-divider collapsible"`) but these don't work as expected. The example of a collapsible listview at the bottom of that demo page has both the list-divider and the content wrapped in a collapsible, which is not quite what I'm after.

Any ideas?

Comment: you could just create a nested collapsible to create that effect

Comment: Thanks @TheWandererr, yeah I think I'll just have to manually style it to look like a list divider. I just thought there might be an easier way. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than nesting collapsibles, I just emulated the behaviour like this:

```
$("li").hide();
$("[data-role='list-divider']").show();
$("[data-role='list-divider']").click(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil("[data-role='list-divider']").toggle();
});
```